# How to get X,Y coordinates of an image in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, coordinates, mouselistener, mouse-listeners

I have an image of a map placed as the icon of a `JLabel`. 
I am using following code to get the X,Y coordinates of the location where the mouse is clicked.
I have put this code in the MouseClick event of the `JLabel`.

```
Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

double X = point.getX();
double Y = point.getY();
```

but the coordinates depend on the location of the `JFrame` form. If the form is moved the coordinates change.

Is there anyway I can freeze the `JFrame`?
Or
Is there anyway I can get a corner of the image as 0,0 and get the other coordinates relative to that? (So I can calculate the actual coordinates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html#getLocation%28%29) returns the mouse co-ordinates relative to the screen. Use the co-ordinates from the `MouseEvent` instead

```
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         double x = e.getX();
         double y = e.getY();
         ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and worked! Thank you! 
But theres a small issue. When i click on the image 
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { } gets called multiple times. Exactly the amount of times i click on the image. Eg: If i'm clicking on it for the 3rd time , the code inside  "public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }"  gets called 3 times.And it increases as the number of times i click increases. Can you explain why this happens? :)

Comment: @Reimius: Could you please check this question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981336/mouselistener-called-multiple-times

Comment: I note you have posted an uncompilable code snippet in your latest question.  No SSCCE?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: What did you mean by Uncompilable? I posted the whole code i used in the button click event. what should i put more than that? Can you please clarify this?

Comment: *"What did you mean by Uncompilable?"*  Try copy/pasting any code snippet and compiling it.  Will it compile without a class declaration & imports?  *"should i put more than that?"* Yes, put an SSCCE. *"Can you please clarify this?"*  Can **you** clarify what part of S-SC-C-E you are confused about?  I am the author of that document, so if there is anything you do not understand, I am well placed to explain.  OTOH I wrote the document so that I did not need to 'type a novel' every time it came up.