# MouseListener called multiple times

Tags: java, swing, coordinates, mouselistener, mouse-listeners

I am using this code to get the X and Y coordinates of an image placed as icon of a jLable.
This method to get the coordinates was suggested by an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977589/how-to-get-x-y-coordinates-of-an-image-in-a-jlable).

```
private void lblMapMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
            lblMap.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    double X = e.getX();
                    double Y = e.getY();
                    System.out.println("X: " + X + "Y: " + Y );
                }
            });
    }
```

When I run this `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }` gets called multiple times. 
Exactly the amount of times I click on the image.

Eg: If I'm clicking on it for the 3rd time , 
X and Y values from the `System.out.println` line , gets printed 3 times.

And it increases as the number of times I click increases. 
Can any of you explain why this happens? And how can I fix it? :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to implement some sort of mouse down or mouse up function.

Comment: Exactly what kind of function are you suggesting? I have tried using this code in the Mouse Pressed event but same thing happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding a new listener again and again when click happens, here.

```
private void lblMapMouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) 
{
    lblMap.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        ...
```

Instead, change your code to this.

```
private void lblMapMouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    double X = e.getX();
    double Y = e.getY();
    System.out.println("X: " + X + "Y: " + Y);
}
```

And it should fix the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it worked. I don't know why i added that extra addMouselistener. May be i read the answer for previous question incorrectly.Anyway Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 5):

it looks for me that every time image is clicked new mouse listener is added.. do also

```
 System.out.println(this)
```

to check from which instance of mouse listener it is actually printed

Comment: Yes i think you are right. It creates multiple mouselisteners. This is the output i got.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7oZzJkamEwajFmcGc/edit?usp=sharing
So,How can i fix that?

Comment: @DirenDantanarayana check Sri Harsha Chilakapati answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem with above code was you are creating new Mouse event with every click on the image.

```
// Create a Mouse pressed Event
mouseLis = new MouseAdapter() {
                        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                            actionMenthod(e);
                        }
                   };
```

Here am attaching the my event to lblMap.

```
       lblMap.addMouseListener(mouseLis);
```

After this event happens you have to remove this event from the lblmap.

```
      lblMap.removeMouseListener(mouseLis);
```

After when I click again only one event will be there then it prints only once.